# Resultado de busca de duas tabelas sem relação

Tags: php, mysql, query, filtro

Tenho uma dúvida se é possível retornar em uma consulta, registros de duas tabelas distintas, sendo que essas tabelas não possuem relação.

Tenho a tabela roupas e tabela acessórios.
Farei um filtro dinâmico para listar roupas(cor,tamanho e preço) e acessórios(categorias).
Inicialmente imaginei modelar uma tabela produtos, roupas e acessórios, sendo que as duas últimas são filhas da primeira(Mas não quero a tabela produtos).

Comment: Se não há relação não pode relacionar... porque tem a tabela acessórios apenas com categorias?

Se simplesmente quer relacionar as roupas a categorias, adiciona um campo categorias na tabela roupas. (partindo do principio de uma relacao 1.*-1)

Comment: Eu só quero que a consulta retorne dados misturados no filtro, tanto de roupas como de acessórios. Acessórios não são roupas por isso imagino não relacionar.

Comment: Discordo do @FabioCardoso não tem porque adicionar o campo de categoria na tabela de roupas, no maximo adicionaria uma coluna id para "ligar" ambas. O que o autor provavelmente quis dizer com relacionar é fazer uma consulta em duas tabelas que não se relacionam usando uma unica query. É possivel sim relacionar ambas, diga-me uma coisa, acessorios são especificos por produtos ou ele pode ir em vários produtos?

Comment: Guilherme, acessórios possuem N categorias (Bolsa, colares, brincos etc..) já as roupas não terão categorias, terão (Tamanho, cor e preço). A minha consulta inicialmente retorna todos o itens da tabela roupas e todos da acessórios. Porém quando clicado em uma categoria de acessórios a consulta deverá listar todos as roupas e apenas o acessórios da categoria selecionada

Comment: Alguma sugestão?